# Restricting requests based on origin for spring boot APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict access to a spring boot REST API based on the origin of the request.
My requirement is to allow requests from a domain, for e.g. `abc.com`, but block the requests from other sources like a REST client like `POSTMAN`.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. I am able to access the API from `POSTMAN`, but I get a CORS error when trying to call the API from `abc.com`.

```
@Component
public class ApiCorsFilters extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "abc.com");
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class WebControllerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("abc.com");
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").
                permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve this sort of access control? If yes, how effective is it?

Comment: I see no  way. All you have is the request, which you could configurate in Postman as you like. You need an authentication for every client, but you could still add that authentication to your request in Postman.